# Clojure (Joodo) deployment on Heroku failing

Tags: heroku, clojure, joodo

I'm having some trouble getting my Joodo application to deploy to Heroku.  According to the deployment instructions here http://joodoweb.com/, we can theoretically deploy without specifying a Procfile.  This causes Heroku to run `lein with-profile production trampoline run` as the default command to launch the project.  This leads to this error:

```
2014-04-26T19:30:46.899454+00:00 app[web.1]: Error encountered performing task 'trampoline' with profile(s): 'production'
2014-04-26T19:30:46.899525+00:00 app[web.1]: Suppressed exit
2014-04-26T19:30:46.899112+00:00 app[web.1]: No :main namespace specified in project.clj.
2014-04-26T19:30:48.275513+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-04-26T19:30:49.093441+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=floating-chamber-7585.herokuapp.com request_id=de532a37-57b1-4ce2-b5c0-c056019eda6b fwd="76.171.76.49" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-04-26T19:30:48.303715+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

I have also tried explicitly setting the Procfile to 'lein ring server' (which is what you run in development).  The error then is:

```
 2014-04-26T21:24:34.229386+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.Exception: No namespace: heepster.view-helpers found
 2014-04-26T21:24:34.221227+00:00 app[web.1]:     :request-method      :get
 2014-04-26T21:24:34.221229+00:00 app[web.1]:     :scheme              :http
 2014-04-26T21:24:34.221232+00:00 app[web.1]:     :server-port         80
 2014-04-26T21:24:34.221235+00:00 app[web.1]:     :session/key         nil
 2014-04-26T21:24:34.229391+00:00 app[web.1]:   at     joodo.views$eval_content.invoke(views.clj:48)
 2014-04-26T21:24:34.221238+00:00 app[web.1]:     :uri                 /}
 2014-04-26T21:24:34.229380+00:00 app[web.1]: 
 2014-04-26    21:24:34.227:WARN:oejs.AbstractHttpConnection:/
 2014-04-26T21:24:34.229395+00:00 app[web.1]:   at joodo.views$render_in_layout.invoke(views.clj:59)
 2014-04-26T21:24:34.229388+00:00 app[web.1]:   at clojure.core$the_ns.invoke(core.clj:3760)
 2014-04-26T21:24:34.229401+00:00 app[web.1]:   at heepster.main$fn__2523.invoke(main.clj:23)
 2014-04-26T21:24:34.229405+00:00 app[web.1]:   at compojure.core$if_route$fn__649.invoke(core.clj:40)
 2014-04-26T21:24:34.229393+00:00 app[web.1]:   at joodo.views$render.invoke(views.clj:52)
 2014-04-26T21:24:34.229409+00:00 app[web.1]:   at compojure.core$routing$fn__667.invoke(core.clj:107)
 2014-04-26T21:24:34.229413+00:00 app[web.1]:   at compojure.core$routing.doInvoke(core.clj:107)
 2014-04-26T21:24:34.229397+00:00 app[web.1]:   at joodo.views$render_template.doInvoke(views.clj:86)
 2014-04-26T21:24:34.229403+00:00 app[web.1]:   at compojure.core$make_route$fn__661.invoke(core.clj:94)
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The error is pretty clear, `No namespace: heepster.view-helpers found`. Do you have a file at `src/heepster/view_helpers.clj` containing a namespace `heepster.view-helpers`? This should be happening in development as well as on Heroku.

Comment: I do have the corresponding file, and it doesn't happen in development.  : (

Comment: Full file name, path, and contents, please.

Comment: https://github.com/heepster/heepster/blob/master/src/clj/heepster/views/view_helpers.clj

You can check it out there.  I've since reorganized the namespace, as you'll see.  Like earlier, this works in development, but not in production, giving me the corresponding "can't find namespace".  Thanks for taking a look!